# Values from $A$ and $B$ to make the expression negative

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

I have this equation:
$$2x^2 +(A+B-1)x + AB, \text{ where } 0<x<1, A>0,B>0$$
I want to know if there is a way of manipulating that equation such that it becomes negative. In other words,
$$2x^2 +(A+B-1)x + AB < 0$$
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it suffices to show that it is non-positive for the 2 endpoints of x, 0 and 1 as the function is concave up.

Comment: Do you mean conditions on A and B so that it may be negative?

Comment: exactly, I want values $A$ and $B$ positives such that the equation becomes negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to give conditions for the quadratic to be negative at $x=0$: $AB<0$, and at $x=1$: 
$$1+A+B+AB<0\iff (A+1)(B+1)<0.$$
Hence the conditions are 
$$\begin{cases}
AB<0\\
(A+1)(B+1)<0
\end{cases}$$
A geometric representation of these conditions in the $(A$-$B)$ plane: $(A,B)$ must be chosen in the overlapping quadrants:

[image]

Comment: But since $A>0$ and $B>0$, then this would imply that no matter what values $A$ and $B$ are, the equation will never be negative, right?

Comment: That's correct. I didn't notice this hypothesis, so I solved the general case.